# Can't do a POST for a new object SPRING DATA REST

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest

I have a spring data rest api for the backend and AngularJs for the front end (mysql as the DB).
I'm trying to add a list of "dictamenes" to an "expediente" using the repositories I made the following JAVA logic

Mixed Java Class ExpedienteDictamen:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="expediente_dictamen")
public class ExpedienteDictamen implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@RestResource(exported=false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Expediente.class, optional=false, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumns(value = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "expediente", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = true)})
private Expediente expediente;
@RestResource(exported=false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Dictamen.class, optional=false, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumns(value = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "dictamen", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = true)})
private Dictamen dictamen;
@Column(name = "fecha_carga")
private Date fechaCarga;
@Column(name = "fecha_mod")
private Date fechaMod;
@Column(name = "usuario_carga")
private String usuarioCarga;
@Column(name = "usuario_mod")
private String usuarioMod;
```

Expediente:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "expediente")
public class Expediente implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "numero_expediente")
private String numeroExpediente;
@Column(name = "acta_recepcion")
private String actaRecepcion;
@Column(name = "acta_aceptacion")
private String actaAceptacion;
@Column(name = "cartilla_medica")
private String cartillaMedica;
@Column(name = "cartilla_medica_obs")
private String cartillaMedicaObs;
@Column(name = "medico_acepta")
private String medicoAcepta;
@Column(name = "cartilla_notificacion")
private String cartillaNotificacion;
@RestResource(exported=false)
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinColumn(name = "solicitud", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Solicitud solicitud;
@RestResource(exported=false)
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinColumn(name = "franquicia", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Franquicia franquicia;
@RestResource(exported=false)
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinColumn(name = "disposicion", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Disposicion disposicion;
@RestResource(exported=false)
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinColumn(name = "paso", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Paso paso;
@OrderBy(value="dictamen")
@RestResource(exported=false)
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "expediente", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<ExpedienteDictamen> expedienteDictamen = new HashSet<ExpedienteDictamen>();
@Column(name = "obs_documentacion")
private String obsDocumetacion;
@Column(name = "documentacion")
private Boolean documentacion;
@Column(name = "juntamedica")
private Boolean juntamedica;
@Column(name = "visa_rehabilitacion")
private Boolean visaRehabilitacion;
@Column(name = "visa_dos")
private Boolean visaDos;
@Column(name = "mesa_entradas")
private Boolean mesaEntradas;
@Column(name = "direccion_nacional")
private Boolean direccionNacional;
@Column(name = "finalizado")
private Boolean finalizado;
@Column(name = "fecha_carga")
private Date fechaCarga;
@Column(name = "fecha_mod")
private Date fechaMod;
@Column(name = "usuario_carga")
private String usuarioCarga;
@Column(name = "usuario_mod")
private String usuarioMod;
```

Dictamen:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dictamen")
public class Dictamen implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "dictamen")
private String dictamen;
@Column(name = "fecha_dictamen")
private Date fechaDictamen;
@Column(name = "numero_dictamen")
private String numeroDictamen;
```

So far everything but saving a ExpedienteDictamen seems to be working fine.

The repos are standard ones using JpaRepository.

When I post to a existing "ExpedienteDictamen" everything works fine, but when I try to create a new one it says this:

```
  Query is: insert into expediente_dictamen (fecha_carga, fecha_mod, usuario_carga, usuario_mod) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
  Query is:
  insert into expediente_dictamen (fecha_carga, fecha_mod, usuario_carga, usuario_mod) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
  2016-08-30 16:17:01.792 DEBUG 30635 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] a.g.s.f.aop.logging.LoggingAspect        : Enter: ar.gob.snr.franquicia.web.rest.errors.ExceptionTranslator.processRuntimeException() with argument[s] = [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement]
  2016-08-30 16:17:01.792 DEBUG 30635 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] a.g.s.f.aop.logging.LoggingAspect        : Exit: ar.gob.snr.franquicia.web.rest.errors.ExceptionTranslator.processRuntimeException() with result = <500 Internal Server Error,ar.gob.snr.franquicia.web.rest.errors.ErrorDTO@6a850e14,{}>
```

Any Ideas?

**Edited.

Comment: Did you check if you are connected to the database?

Comment: Maybe trying to save empty content to any field who is required to have content?

Comment: Yes since I can post anything but that, I can even update an actual "ExpedienteDictamen"
I'm not sure about that. I might be passing the "Expediente" incorrectly. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried posting it with Dictamen and Expediente both blank and it works.
So it means I'm not passing those values right. Any ideas?

Comment: How are u creating ExpedienteDictamen without expediente and dictamen values since those are not nullable? And since these properties also have insertable and updatable as false, records of ExpedienteDictamen could only be created using Expediente/Dictamen entities.

Comment: Changed ExpedienteDictamen, now I can write the "dictamen part", but not the expediente part...

Comment: Can you also please put the query log and exception which you see after modifying ExpedienteDictamen to have all fields as insertable, updatable and nullable true. Also please try to put the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are u creating ExpedienteDictamen without expediente and dictamen values since those are not nullable?

Since these properties also have insertable and updatable as false, records of ExpedienteDictamen could be created using Expediente/Dictamen entities

Comment: I can post from expediente and get the values for the "dictamenes" to write on the DB, but not the values for "Expediente"

Comment: I didn't get you, what I mean is you cannot update ExpedienteDictamen -> expediente and dictamen attributes, by posting ExpedienteDictamen entity, since those are annotated as updatable and insertable false.

Comment: Changed that, testing it now, didn't realise it.